# How to find if a sub string with XPath 1.0

Tags: xml, xpath, sonarqube, xpath-1.0

I am having trouble trying to find an occurrence of a specific sub string in XPATH 1.0. This expression will be used in the code review tool *SonarQube* to set constraints.

This is the expression I have currently in XPATH 3.0 and I have done some research to find the conversion but it seems this expression the syntax is correct in XPATH 3.0 as it is in 1.0. Am I overlooking something or simply misinformed

```
//*[contains(.,'@example.com')]
```

To my understanding this uses the *contains()* function native to XPATH 1.0 to search any `/descendant-or-self::node()/` path before it to contain the attribute `example.com`.

Comment: Can you share HTML sample along with current and desired outputs?

Comment: @Andersson so i'm trying to actually parse an XML file but here's what a hypothetical XML file to parse and the desired output would be to return true if the sub string is found                                                                                   
```<root xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
 <employees>
  <employee id="1">
                <name>Johnny Dape</name>                                                       
                <email email = "example@example.com" /></employee>
 </employees></root>``` I want it to catch that hardcoded email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`//*[contains(.,'@example.com')]` means *"find node of any type with **text content** that contains substring '@example.com'"*. If you want to *"find node with **attribute** that contains '@example.com' in its value"* you need:

- in **any** attribute:

  ```
  //*[contains(@*, "@example.com")]
  ```
- in **specific** attribute:

  ```
  //*[contains(@email, "@example.com")]
  ```

If you want to get value of required `@attribute`:

```
//*[contains(@email, "@example.com")]/@email
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. Very informative answer!